# watchPosition combined with polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to find a way to add a polyline as the coordinates change, i have tried every possible combination of guessing that i can think of, also including googles own docs for "complex polylines" and i have had no luck.

If anyone can shine some light it'd be much appriciated as i am now completely stuck with this!

```
function startTrack() {
    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout : 5000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessTrack, onErrorTrack, options);

    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    };
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);

}

function onSuccessTrack(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

var path = poly.getPath();

path.push(google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the path of the polyline:

```
function startTrack() {
    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, timeout : 5000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessTrack, onErrorTrack, options);

    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
    };
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);

}

function onSuccessTrack(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  var path = poly.getPath();

  path.push(google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
  poly.setPath(path); // ** update path for polyline **
}
```

Comment: Indeed i had missed that bit off in my frenzy of trying things out!

I am now getting errors from my js file as well VM12015 which i can only presume is something maps related which are:

`Uncaught InvalidValueError: at index 0: not an instance of LatLng`

`VM12015:64 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`

Comment: If you have other issues, you will need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates those issues.

Comment: I think i've solved the issue, the array that was being used to populate the coordinates was located within the onSuccess function, i've also rearranged the code and called the onSuccess before the startTrack and moved the code around and it appears to be working now.

I dont supposed theres a way to increase when to check for a new set of coordinates? I've tried using maximumAge and it seems to ignore it and add a new poly point as soon as the coordinates change